# Javascript-like TCP socket client written in python?

Tags: javascript, python, events, tcp, tcpclient

In the page http://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/0.4 the first snippet (the "Low Level API example") is very much like the client example in http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#example.

What I'm interested in is if is there any possibility of making a TCP client that is even driven, like the "JavaScript websocket-like API example" on that first webpage, that executes actions when for an example a message arrives. How can I achieve this ?
I found [this example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/simpleclient.py) that uses twisted. Any other (better ?) ways to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) and specifically at [tornado.iostream — Convenient wrappers for non-blocking sockets](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/iostream.html).